# microchip sound recognition library (SR_L.h) conflicting qualifiers with dspic30F6014 header

Tags: c, header-files, conflict, pic, microchip

dsPIC30F6014 with Sound recognition library [conflicting type qualifiers for 'WREG0']
When using the SRL (Sound recognition library) it has its own header file SR_L.h and when using this in project which already has #include  an error occurs

```
conflicting type qualifiers for 'WREG0'
conflicting type qualifiers for 'WREG1'
conflicting type qualifiers for 'WREG2'
```

Because these in both header files i.e. SR_Lib.h and p30F6014.h. The SRL is meant to be run on p30F6014 then why is this occurring?

I've also posted this question on microchip forum, from where the [sample project](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m796116.aspx#796116) can be downloaded.

The definition in SR_Lib header is as:

```
#define LINK_INTERRUPT 1
void (*WREG0)(void) = (LINK_INTERRUPT) ? _DCIInterrupt : _T4Interrupt;
void (*WREG1)(void) = (LINK_INTERRUPT) ? _AddressError : _MathError;
void (*WREG2)(void) = (LINK_INTERRUPT) ? _StackError   : _StackError;
```

in MCU header

```
extern volatile unsigned int WREG0 __attribute__((__sfr__,__deprecated__,__unsafe__));
```

Comment: Those are some pretty crazy-different types. One's a pointer to a function, and the other is an integer. I think that you've gone badly off the rails somewhere in configuring this project.

Comment: @MarkBessey The project configuration has been done according to the steps mentioned on page 51 of the user guide on location http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/dsPIC_Speech_Recognition_User_Guide_70140a.pdf